# how to set truncate-lines in org-mode in spacemacs by default

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, wrapping, line-truncation

Whenever I open up an `.org` file in spacemacs, the `truncate-lines` variable is set to `t`.

How can I make `truncate-lines` be set to `nil` by default in org-mode in the org-layer for spacemacs?

I would like lines to be wrapped in org-mode when they are about to go over the edge of the screen.

---

I've read different things online that talk about how to fix this problem.

One suggestion is to set the `org-startup-truncated` variable to `nil` in `dotspacemacs/user-config`.

I've tried doing that like this:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq org-startup-truncated nil))
```

However, that doesn't appear to work.  When I open up a `.org` file, `truncate-lines` is still set to `t`.

I've also tried adding a hook to org mode to to call `spacemacs/toggle-truncate-lines-off` automatically:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-truncate-lines-off))
```

This also doesn't appear to work.  When I open up a `.org` file, `truncate-lines` is still set to `t`.

However, after opening a `.org` file, I am able to manually run the `spacemacs/toggle-truncate-lines-off` in order to set `truncate-lines` to `nil`.

Just in case, here is my [`.spacemacs`](https://github.com/cdepillabout/docs/blob/396187ebf918ca68e2757228a2677767efdd1de0/dot_files/dot_spacemacs) file.  You can see my multiple attempts at setting `truncate-lines`.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer (not so good) for turning off `truncate-line` is:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'spacemacs/toggle-truncate-lines-off)
```

But if what you want is line wrap in org mode. This is not a good solution because:

1. `truncate-line` starts the new line at the beginning of the window, but not the beginning of the previous line.
2. It also adds small arrows on both side of window edge which is annoy in my experience.
3. The `j` and `k` doesn't work for continued lines, even worse, in Spacemacs' org mode `gj` and `gk` are mapped to headline forward/backward.

A better solution is to use [visual line mode](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_long_line_wrap.html) with word wrap disabled. Visual line mode solves all above problems, but it enables `word-wrap`. Disabling word wrap makes it behaves more like truncate-line. Here's an example:

```
(defun org-line-wrap ()
  (spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation-on)
  (setq-local word-wrap nil))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-line-wrap)
```

BTW if you're confuse for something, you can use `C-h v` to check variable documentation.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines nil)))
```

or replace `truncate-lines` with another wrap style.

Comment: Hooks take symbols rather than expressions, so your `add-hook` won't work.  OP also asked for spacemacs-specific suggestions.